# How to backup iCloud only files?

Tags: icloud, backup, time-machine

How can I securely backup files, which are purged from the local harddrive due to the Optimize-Storage feature in macOS?

- They are **NOT** backed up in Timemachine
- They are **NOT** backed up with CCC ([see here](https://bombich.com/nl/kb/ccc5/limitations-online-only-placeholder-files))

Currently I am manually copying them to an external drive but it does **NOT** seem, that they get downloaded doing this: It seems to only copy the placeholder files.

There has to be a way, to securely back them up